# GitHub get download count from specific file

Tags: github, github-api

Is there a way that I can get the download count of a specific file in a repository (downloaded via `raw.githubusercontent.com`)?

I'm not meaning the Github Releases download count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot count download times for a specific file.

You can count download time for a release artifact

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#list-releases

[image]